# Google+ integration chrome extension issue

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-plus, content-security-policy

I am trying to integrate google+ API with my google chrome extension. My integration based on this quick start example introduced here:
https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript

I have migrated all inline javascript code to separate files, added content_security_policy line in my manifest.json file:

> "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.googleapis.com/ https://plus.google.com/ https://apis.google.com/ https://accounts.google.com/ https://ssl.gstatic.com https://csi.gstatic.com https://developers.google.com; object-src 'self'"

The problem is following. When I click on the Google+ button I get following error message:

> Refused to execute JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: `"script-src 'self' https://www.googleapis.com/ https://plus.google.com/ https://apis.google.com/ https://accounts.google.com/ https://ssl.gstatic.com https://csi.gstatic.com https://developers.google.com"`.

Which is obviously unhappy with content_security_policy.  It throws this exception on line 468 in this file:

https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.aop9WHMC8-8.O/m=client,plusone,signin/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=EQ/rs=AItRSTNUM79OpqDtwYl6kryPkOs00evROQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0.

It seems it is trying to embed inline script and execute it after, which violates Content Security Policy. 
The same exception appears when I click to "Accept" button in the popup. As a result popup window hangs without response.

Do you have any experience with that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Google +1 in a content script without Content Security Policy error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211060/how-to-use-google-1-in-a-content-script-without-content-security-policy-error)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `manifest.json`:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://apis.google.com/; object-src 'self'"
```