# How to use Google +1 in a content script without Content Security Policy error?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-plus, google-plus-one

I'm trying to build chrome extension that uses [+1 google api](https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js).

My manifest.json looks like:

```
"manifest_version": 2,
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'",
...
"matches": ["http://demosite.com/*"],
"js": ["js/jquery.js","js/social/plusone.js"]
```

As you can see I've whitelisted apis.google.com.

My plusone.js looks like:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js";
head.appendChild(script);
    
$('li.subscription').before('<g:plusone></g:plusone>');
```

As you can see I just inject script tag from whitelisted site.

Unfortunately, when I load a page I got an error:

> Refused to load the script
> apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.ru.Fqrb4MMzOT8.O/m…sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=IQ/rs=AItRSTNEKbnLkdtNZVz4hKH7VV4tY98scw/cb=gapi.loaded_0'
> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> "script-src 'self'".

All similar questions here say I should whitelist site with content_security_policy, but I've done it as you can see. Are there any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extension's [Content security policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) **only applies to extension pages**, **not content scripts**.
When you insert a `<script>` tag, it becomes subject of the page's CSP, so changing the CSP string in the manifest file won't have any effect.

To solve the problem, I suggest to load `scriptTagContext.js` before your other content script. First read [README.md](https://github.com/Rob--W/chrome-api/blob/master/scriptTagContext/README.md) to understand the technique, then get it from https://github.com/Rob--W/chrome-api/tree/master/scriptTagContext.

## Example: G+1 on every Github page

I'm taking Github as an example, because it enforces a strict Content security policy.

#### manifest.json

```js
{
    "name": "Google +1 on Github",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["scriptTagContext.js", "contentscript.js"],
        "matches": ["*://*.github.com/*"]
    }],
    "permissions": [
        "*://apis.google.com/*"
    ]
}
```

#### scriptTagContext.js

Get it from https://raw.github.com/Rob--W/chrome-api/master/scriptTagContext/scriptTagContext.js

#### contentscript.js

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);

// Next snippet is equivalent to jQuery's $('body').prepend('<g:plusone/>')
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<g:plusone></g:plusone>');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't make you lib work. What I've done:1)added scriptTagContext.js to my extension 2)added it to contentscript BEFORE main script 3)inserted example with boolean into my content script => it shows undefined both time

Comment: @user2786037 So, have you read the README, including the note "The source of external scripts are loaded using `XMLHttpRequest`, so **you need to declare the script URL or host at the "permissions" section of the manifest file**."?

Comment: please see update of my comment. I use only example with inserting script in page

Comment: @user2786037 What boolean..? You don't have to modify anything else in your existing code if you want to get Google+ to work. I've just created a demo extension which shows the G+1 button on Github (a site with a strict CSP), and it showed up just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in my scipt! Everything works fine, thank you!

Comment: @user2786037 You're welcome! I've edited my answer to include a minimal example, for future reference.

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping to use this with a packaged app, but it won't work. 'content_scripts' is only allowed for extensions and legacy packaged apps, but this is a packaged app.

Comment: Is this script still working for you guys? I'm getting "Refused to frame 'http://...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src render.githubusercontent.com"