# Redirect to Google Gmail SignIn screen from Login Page button in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, browser-extension

I have started learning about chrome extensions and created a welcome page. I have added a simple Login screen that having username and password and receiving the values in my web api. Now I am trying to use Gmail api which will redirect users to Gmail login screen and let them login through it.

I am not able to decide how to use [chrome.identity](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity) for the same. Before posting this, I have searched the site and got confused by answers. Some of them are talking about **Firebase** and some of them are talking about **oauth**.

Here is my manifest.json sample:

```
{

"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Sample Web api Extension",        
"version": "1.5.2",       
"permissions": [
"storage",    
"tabs",   
"management",
"identity",
"https://accounts.google.com/*",
"https://www.googleapis.com/*"
],
"oauth2": {   
"client_id": "XXXccsdfdsfDWOQU#O@v.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"scopes": [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile" ]
},

"icons": {
"48": "img/logo.png"
},

"background": {
"page": "background.html",
"persistent": true
},  
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'",
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "img/off.png"
},

}
```

Landing page having a button :

```
<div class="buttons">
            <button id="login-btn" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google btn-flat" tabindex="3"><i class="fa fa-gmail"></i>Sign in Using Google</button>
            <!--<button id="cancel-btn" class="btn btn-default" tabindex="4">Cancel</button>-->
            <button class="btn-link" id="help-link" tabindex="5">Need help</button>
        </div>
```

So May I know what should I do next? Sorry, If I am sounding like script kiddies and not able to decide next thing. Any sample code would be also helpful.

Thanks

[google extension sample link--dead now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194659/google-integration-chrome-extension-issue)

Answer (score 0):

So, Finally Myself figured it out that what to do next. Sharing here just in case someone or even me required in future :)

Step 1) Create a Login.js file and add below code:

```
 var listenBtnClick = function () {
    console.log("Hello, going to authorize user js");
    authorizeMethod.getAccessToken();
}
```

Step 2) Create Authorize.js file and below code:

```
  var REDIRECT_URL = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL("oauth2");

  var CLIENT_ID = "RandomNumber.apps.googleusercontent.com"; // grab this from console.developers.google.com

  var SCOPES = ["openid", "email", "profile"]; //take one or array of properties. 
var joinedScopes = SCOPES.join('');

var AUTH_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=" + CLIENT_ID + "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(REDIRECT_URL) + "&scope=" + encodeURIComponent(joinedScopes) + "&response_type=token";
```

Step 3)  Get access token and then validate it with returned access token:

```
var getAccessToken = function () {
    console.log("getAccessToken")
    return authorize().then(validate);
};
```

PS: I will continue updating this thread with more steps.